# Issues running ChromeDriver or FirefoxDriver for Selenium on Java

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So, I'm trying to run my Java code on 16.04 Ubuntu with 80 version Chrome.
Having a hard time here.

1) ChromeDriver (https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3e8ab7e944d02fe872c3454d17af31a5):

```
Error: 'Chrome exited abnormally'.
```

As I understand, this issue doesn't have one sure solution.
But I've tried most, that I've found in here and on other forums.

Here's how my ChromeOptions look now:

```
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox", "--disable-gpu", "--disable-extensions"
      // "--headless",
      // ", --remote-debugging-port=9222",
      // "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--allow-running-insecure-content", "--disable-web-security"
      // , "start-maximized", "window-size=1024,768", "--single-process"
    );
```

Versions should be okay, as both Chrome and ChromeDriver versions are 80 now.

2) FirefoxDriver
("--no-sandbox" set, "headless" not set cause WebGL can't be used with it)

After I didn't have luck with Chrome, I decided to check FirefoxDriver.

```
Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified
ERROR [2020-03-25 18:57:49,002] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 1113fc9103a6ab81
! org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

I've found a guide on how to set display variable and start Selenium 
([Selenium Error: no display specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653127/selenium-error-no-display-specified)).
I followed it and Selenium is running now. But, the error is still the same.

What did I do wrong?)
Thanks in advance for your help.

Maybe, I should try some other driver
(these r the most commonly used, from what I see, though).

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: Also you should get the chrome driver from there:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: @Jortega 

using Java8, my chrome driver version is 80, as it should be for Chrome of 80 version