# Why this Twitter login UI script only works in my developer environment and not on the server?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, twitter

Twitter made a fundamental change not so long ago: you cannot view a user's timeline any more if you are not logged in. That broke all my scraping code. The code bellow works on my developer environment, but not on the server. In my developer environment it's also headless. As you can see I tried to sprinkle in sleeps to figure out if the script is moving too fast.

The script fails by not finding the password input. That input comes into view after filling in the username / email input and pressing the Next button. After filling in the password I'd need to click the "Log in" button.

```
TWITTER_URL_BASE = "https://twitter.com/"
SELENIUM_INSTANCE_WAIT = 1

@classmethod
def _get_driver(cls):
    driver = None

    firefox_options = FirefoxOptions()
    firefox_options.headless = True
    firefox_options.add_argument("width=1920")
    firefox_options.add_argument("height=1080")
    firefox_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
    firefox_options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653127/selenium-error-no-display-specified
    # export MOZ_HEADLESS=1
    firefox_options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox"
    # firefox_options.set_preference("extensions.enabledScopes", 0)
    # firefox_options.set_preference("gfx.webrender.all", False)
    # firefox_options.set_preference("layers.acceleration.disabled", True)
    firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary("/usr/bin/firefox")
    firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile()
    firefox_options.binary = "/usr/bin/firefox"  # firefox_binary
    firefox_options.profile = firefox_profile
    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
    capabilities["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"
    firefox_options._caps = capabilities
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(
            firefox_profile=firefox_profile,
            firefox_binary=firefox_binary,
            options=firefox_options,
            desired_capabilities=capabilities,
        )
    except Exception as e:
        cls.log_response("_get_driver", 500, "Crash: {}".format(e))
        cls.log_response("_get_driver", 500, traceback.format_exc())

    return driver

def _login_scraper_user(cls, driver, scraper_account):
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get(TWITTER_URL_BASE)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        lambda dr: dr.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete"
    )
    time.sleep(SELENIUM_INSTANCE_WAIT)
    username_inputs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[name='text']")
    if not username_inputs:
        return False

    username_input_parent = (
        username_inputs[0].find_element_by_xpath("..").find_element_by_xpath("..")
    )
    username_input_parent.click()
    time.sleep(SELENIUM_INSTANCE_WAIT)
    username_inputs[0].click()
    time.sleep(SELENIUM_INSTANCE_WAIT)
    username_inputs[0].send_keys(scraper_account["username"])
    time.sleep(SELENIUM_INSTANCE_WAIT)
    next_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[text()="Next"]')
    if not next_buttons:
        return False

    next_buttons[0].click()
    time.sleep(SELENIUM_INSTANCE_WAIT)

    password_inputs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[name='password']")
    if not password_inputs:
        return False

    password_input_parent = (
        password_inputs[0].find_element_by_xpath("..").find_element_by_xpath("..")
    )
    password_input_parent.click()
    time.sleep(SELENIUM_INSTANCE_WAIT)
    password_inputs[0].click()
    time.sleep(SELENIUM_INSTANCE_WAIT)
    password_inputs[0].send_keys(scraper_account["password"])
    time.sleep(SELENIUM_INSTANCE_WAIT)
    login_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[text()="Log in"]')
    if not login_buttons:
        return False

    login_buttons[0].click()
    time.sleep(SELENIUM_INSTANCE_WAIT)

    if driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        '//span[text()="Boost your account security"]'
    ):
        close_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
            "div[data-testid='app-bar-close']"
        )
        if not close_buttons:
            return False

        close_buttons[0].click()

    driver.implicitly_wait(0)
    return True
```

This is an old version of Selenium because the server lags behind due to technical debt (it's an IaaS). I'm using the same ancient Selenium, however my Firefox is fresh.

---

Just a little follow-up:
The whole API pricing -> scraping (I predicted this on the 1st of May) -> scrape prevention fight unnecessarily reached the user level: https://www.cnbc.com/2023/07/03/users-flock-to-twitter-competitor-bluesky-after-elon-musk-imposes-rate-limits.html
Congratulations!

Comment: Twitter has a well-defined API.  You should need to resort to hackery.

Comment: @TimRoberts Before the Thanos snap on May 1st we were using the API, however their new pricing is absolutely out of touch with reality unfortunately. There's no way we could afford that. I would be happy to pay a reasonable price. It's an indescribable pain to fiddle with screen scraping, it's almost like a sorcery. Believe me the last thing I want to do is scrape and rely on UI scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing the situation, it seems like that the possible reason is that the scraper accounts get flagged

> In order to protect your account from suspicious activity, we've sent a confirmation code to tw************@g****.***. Enter it below to sign in.
> Why am I being asked for this information?

I tried to apply some anti-scrape prevention measures, but ultimately the requirement of an account makes it super simple for Twitter to tell apart scrapers. I won't go to the length of farming email accounts and register a new Twitter every time for a scrape. It's probably **game over** you guys.

[Twitter's new API plan costs up to $2.5 million per year](https://mashable.com/article/twitter-elon-musk-paid-enterprise-api-access-pricing)

I mean even Microsoft decided not to pay: [Microsoft’s refusal to pay for Twitter’s API has outraged Elon Musk](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/microsoft-refusal-pay-twitter-api-093800826.html)

Probably the new $5000/mo tier won't help either.

---

Update: this whole shenanigan got to the point that it even affects regular users. I predicted that people will scrape, I also predicted anti scraping measures and anti scrape prevention measures. But I NEVER thought this whole issue will get to the surface of the end users. This is pathetic! Facepalm!
https://www.cnbc.com/2023/07/03/users-flock-to-twitter-competitor-bluesky-after-elon-musk-imposes-rate-limits.html