# bash script opening firefox browser from browser

Tags: linux, bash, firefox, browser

I am checking a shell script using:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-Type: text/plain"
echo
echo "Time is:"
date
/usr/bin/firefox http://www.google.fr &
```

If I run the script in a terminal I get the date and I can open the firefox browser.
But if I run the script using a browser (localhost/cgi-bin/scriptest) I get the date

```
Time is:
Mon Sep  9 14:18:47 CEST 2013
```

**but the firefox browser is not open.**
Does anyone know why the firefox browser appears if I run the script using a terminal and not from the browser? any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're running your script on a terminal under same user and same X session. The DISPLAY variable should be set. Add this line to know more info:

```
...
echo "DISPLAY: \"$DISPLAY\", whoami: $(whoami)"
/usr/bin/firefox http://www.google.fr  ## No need to add &.
```

Your user should be the same as the one on your X session.
If DISPLAY has no value, try setting to `:0.0` as a quick hack:

```
...
export DISPLAY=':0.0'
/usr/bin/firefox http://www.google.fr
```

If it still doesn't work, try to refer to some threads about `DISPLAY` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784404/how-can-i-specify-a-display).

Comment: Hi, my browser answer is: DISPLAY: "", whoami: www-data. In the terminal the answer is: DISPLAY: ":0.0", whoami: angel. It seems the problem is related to the www-data.... different user. I don't see any solution ....

Comment: @anraT Why do you have to run it as a different user and terminal?

Comment: I would like to run firefox using the same user but I don't understand the www-data user... I think it is a Apache configuration?

Comment: I have changed the /etc/apache2/envvars. I have changed www-data to angel. Maintenant I have in the browser DISPLAY:":0.0" (using export DISPLAY=':0.0') and whoami: angel. The same result than the terminal but firefox doesn't appear...

Comment: @anraT What I actually wanted to know is, why run it from apache server? You can also redirect error messages from your browser and read it afterwards: `/usr/bin/firefox http://www.google.fr &>/home/angel/log.txt`. I haven't tried running a browser or any X-based application from a daemon yet so that might be all I could help sorry.