# How to run webdriver test cases on remote staging server(ubuntu) using jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, webdriver, maven-3, phantomjs

1. I pushed the code on github
2. I have configured Jenkins on
   `staging.website.com:8xxx` , its a Ubuntu machine
3. I am able to access this ubuntu machine via putty.exe from my windows7 machine
4. I am able to fetch the code on github via Jenkins means I am able to run the build via Jenkins but it fails as **Problem:** I am not able to launch the browser.

**I tried**

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
             capability.setCapability("platform", Platform.LINUX);
             capability.setCapability("binary", "usr/bin/firefox");
             driver= new FirefoxDriver();
             driver.get("mytestproject.com");
```

but it gives error( though I am using latest selenium jar 2.35.0, tried maven clean and restart of server) :

```
 Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: Error: no display specified Error: no display specified Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: '8df0c6bedf70ff9f22c647788f9fe9c8d22210e2', time: '2013-08-17 12:46:41' System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.5.0-21-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_25' Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:251)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:195)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
```

I have checked using `sudo lsof -i :7055`that nothing is using this port (via putty on remote ubuntu machine)
But after reading many forums I couldnt solve it. So I tried to use phantomjs but it also gave error :
I tried :

```
dCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            dCaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
            dCaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);

            driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dCaps);

            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            driver.get(Prod);
```

It gave red line below `driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dCaps);` . Actually I dont know how to use Phantom.js in Maven project.
What I want to achieve : I want to run test case on this remote ubuntu staging server, nomatter headless (ghostdriver) or firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be failing from Jenkins because it is running in a new terminal window with no display defined. It appears as though the Firefox process doesn't allow this.

```
"Error: no display specified"
```

This might help:
[How can I specify a display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784404/how-can-i-specify-a-display)

Answer (score 0):

Why you not let it to use default Firefox binary? Jenkins need only Firefox that is installed for All Users. If i remember correctly firefox is default in any Ubuntu.

```
 Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055;
```

Comment: If you have no X installed on your staging machine then it will not run firefox. 

You can use Xvfb to run headless (and vnc onto it) with these instructions http://www.labelmedia.co.uk/blog/setting-up-selenium-server-on-a-headless-jenkins-ci-build-machine.html

or use phantomjs as a totally headless browser using the webdriver approach

    `./phantomjs --webdriver=5558 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://localhost:4444`

Comment: @Andrian I do not understand what you are suggesting. I have already mentioned that I have used but that didnt work and gave error " Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055;".Firefox didnt work so I wanted to use phantomjs. What's your solution to this.

Comment: I had something like that issue on Windows when Jenkins runs as Windows Service he cant find Chrome Binary, only solution was to run through my account or installed Chrome for all Users. I never tried on Unix...

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn could you please share the piece of code you think would work

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn I like to use completely headless mode using phantomjs and I tried but that gave error please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734664/running-ghostdriver-using-java-gives-error)