# error starting tomcat - no display specified

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to install [Ganib(project management tool)](http://help.ganib.com/questions/4/ganib-installation-linux), which make use of tomcat. After setup, I try to execute Start_ganib.sh, which ultimately try to start tomcat and fails with following error:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /tmp/download/Ganib-1.3_with_jre/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /tmp/download/Ganib-1.3_with_jre/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /tmp/download/Ganib-1.3_with_jre/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:       ../../jre-lin/
Error: no display specified
```

Note: tomcat/bin/startup.sh and tomcat/bin/catalina.sh implicitly executed during this process.

**Edit:**

I tried doing:

> export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0

but its showing another error message:

> Error: cannot open display: localhost:0.0

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784404/how-can-i-specify-a-display

Comment: Thanks, I tried and taken the required measures, now the error its showing is, "Error: cannot open display".

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the above error (assuming you do not require x-windows), you can startup tomcat in headless mode. Edit file **catalina.sh** and add the following to **JAVA_OPTS**

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Comment: Has it accepted that option ? You might want to add an echo to JAVA_OPTS to validate.