# Error: no display specified

Tags: firefox, rhel

I am trying to open firefox browser on redhat server using firefox command but i get following error message.

```
firefox
Error: no display specified
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784404/how-can-i-specify-a-display

Comment: I chekced the solution but still it does not work. i changed Display to 0:0 still Error "Error: cannot open display: :0.0". I got same message with 0:1 also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I specify a display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784404/how-can-i-specify-a-display)