# Connect to X server from the shell

Tags: shell, xserver

Is there a way to connect to the X server from the .sh script? I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:1
BASEDIR=`dirname "${0}"`
cd "$BASEDIR"
python_header.py
```

but no luck.

Comment: In which sense is this script trying to "connect" and how does it fail?

Comment: This is the error in the log: No protocol specified
Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?

Comment: But you get that from the Python script then, not from this shell script? Is DISPLAY set to the right value?

Comment: How would I set it to the right value?

Comment: You need to find out what the correct value for the display you want to connect to is and use that.

Comment: Could you elaborate please. I don't know how to get the correct value.

Comment: Then why do you believe `DISPLAY=:1` would work? Anyway, see if it’s already set in your current session, and/or just guess that `DISPLAY=:0.0` is probably a better wild guess.

Comment: please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784404/how-can-i-specify-a-display) if it helps you finding the right value for the display.

Comment: Where is the script being run? If it's run by a user in an X session, they should already have DISPLAY set to the correct value (and you shouldn't change it).

Comment: If it's being run by something like `cron` (which is outside any X sessions running on the host), then the value you need is very fact-intensive and depends on the security measures in place on your particular system (which may include Xauthority cookies and the like).

Comment: I typed echo $Display in my terminal and it gives me :0, then I added export DISPLAY=:0 to my script the error is the same. No protocol specified Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update for those who might have the same problem: The following link

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/xhost-cannot-open-display/

and then adding this to my code:

```
     export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

solved the problem