# last command in linux shows `:0` in 3rd column, what does it mean?

Tags: linux

I want to write a shell script sort out the data that `last` command shows.
I got this in my server.

```
 root    pts/0        10.168.136.175     Wed Sep 14 14:24 - 14:54   (00:29)        
 root    :0                              Mon Sep 12 10:34 - 11:00   (00:25)       
 reboot  system boot  2.6.18-308.el5PA   Sun Sep 11 11:31           (86+03:05)
```

I did some search, there are some saying `:0.0` in the 3rd column means login locally, second column means what kind of terminal been use, like `pts` and `tty`.

But what does the `:0` in line 2 second column in my log?
I am using redhat 6.5.

Comment: It looks like a X11 display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means local computer. Generally each session represented by pairs `ip_address:display_number`. When you logged in locally the IP address is omitted. That's why there is nothing before `:`. Display number is actually the session number from the specified IP address. So, 0 means the first session

Comment: Display number does not represent a session number, it represents a display/screen pair. See [How can I specify a display?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/784404/45249) for more information.

Comment: @mouviciel You are right. I've used the term 'session', because it's more intuitive. For many people that are not acquainted with X Server terminology the term 'display' is misleading.