# Extracting text from clipboard fails when running on Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, clipboard

I have a Selenium Java test copying table grid values to clipboard. Then I'm extracting the clipboard content with the following method:

```java
public static String extractTextFromClipboard(){
    try {
        return (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    }catch (Exception e){
        ConsoleLogger.error("Failed to extract text from clipboard " + e.getMessage());
        return "";
    }
}
```

and if works just fine when I run the tests locally.
But when I run this test on Jenkins it fails with the following error:

```
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
```

I saw several questions here dealing with the above error but I still do not understand what can I do to fix my issue?
Are there alternative ways to extract clipboard content so it will work for me?

Comment: What is the Jenkins host you are running your jobs on? Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784415/3730626) seem helpful?

Comment: I don't actually know, I'm writing Selenium tests and infrastructure, need to ask devops guy about that

Comment: sounds like you need a display to have a clipboard.  The error you are receiving is telling you there is no display or "virtual" display.

Comment: I'm not really understand how it works when Selenium tests are running on Jenkins, but I know we run our tests in regular, not headless mode. So I do not understand why this difference comes when running not locally. I will try to ask our devops engineers

Answer (score 1):

**Possible solution to your problem:**

1. One potential solution is to use a virtual display such as Xvfb (X virtual framebuffer) This will allow the clipboard access code to run without errors. You can install Xvfb on your Jenkins server and then start a virtual display before running your tests.

> sudo apt-get install xvfb

```
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
export DISPLAY=:99
mvn test
```

2. OR YOU could try using a different library for accessing the clipboard content that does not require an X11 display. For example, you can use the **JavaFX library.**

> ```
>  <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
>       <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
>       <version>16</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```
>
> import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
> import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
>
> ```
> public static String extractTextFromClipboard(){
>     Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
>     if (clipboard.hasString()) {
>         return clipboard.getString();
>     } else {
>         ConsoleLogger.error("Failed to extract text from clipboard");
>         return "";
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I've tried your solutions 2 and 3. None worked for me. I added the dependencies in pom, but in the class I see "can not resolve symbol". `import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;` - `javafx` is not defined, `import org.apache.commons.cli.Clipboard;` - `cli` is not defined.